# R Package Test Failure in utils::packageVersion(x) but call works on command line

Tags: r

I am testing a package before I release the update of it to CRAN. I get the following output from it:

```r
> devtools::check(remote = TRUE, manual = TRUE)
══ Documenting ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
ℹ Updating healthyverse documentation
ℹ Loading healthyverse

══ Building ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX14FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX17FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX20FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
── R CMD build ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\steve\Documents\GitHub\healthyverse/DESCRIPTION'
─  preparing 'healthyverse': (408ms)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  installing the package to build vignettes
✔  creating vignettes (10.3s)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building 'healthyverse_1.0.2.9000.tar.gz'
   
══ Checking ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_               : TRUE
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                      : TRUE
• _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                     : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_PACKAGES_USED_IGNORE_UNUSED_IMPORTS_: FALSE
• NOT_CRAN                                     : true
── R CMD check ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  using log directory 'C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUxN10L/file3b9477a448b2/healthyverse.Rcheck'
─  using R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
─  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
─  using session charset: UTF-8
─  using option '--as-cran'
✔  checking for file 'healthyverse/DESCRIPTION'
─  this is package 'healthyverse' version '1.0.2.9000'
─  package encoding: UTF-8
N  checking CRAN incoming feasibility (16.5s)
   Maintainer: 'Steven Sanderson <blahblah@somemailhost.com>'
   
   Version contains large components (1.0.2.9000)
✔  checking package namespace information ...
✔  checking package dependencies (1.6s)
✔  checking if this is a source package ...
✔  checking if there is a namespace
✔  checking for executable files (418ms)
✔  checking for hidden files and directories ...
✔  checking for portable file names
✔  checking serialization versions
E  checking whether package 'healthyverse' can be installed (3.1s)
   Installation failed.
   See 'C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUxN10L/file3b9477a448b2/healthyverse.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
   
   See
     'C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUxN10L/file3b9477a448b2/healthyverse.Rcheck/00check.log'
   for details.
   
   
── R CMD check results ───────────────────────────────────────── healthyverse 1.0.2.9000 ────
Duration: 23.2s

❯ checking whether package 'healthyverse' can be installed ... ERROR
  See below...

❯ checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
  Maintainer: 'Steven Sanderson <blahblah@somemailhost.com>'
  
  Version contains large components (1.0.2.9000)

── Install failure ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

* installing *source* package 'healthyverse' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'healthyverse':
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'healthyverse', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion(x)
  error: there is no package called 'tidyAML'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/steve/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUxN10L/file3b9477a448b2/healthyverse.Rcheck/healthyverse'

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 1 note ✖
```

Now when I call the offending line:

```r
> as.character(unclass(utils::packageVersion("tidyAML"))[[1]])
[1] "0" "0" "1"
```

Not sure what gives here.

** UPDATE **
When I run `devtools::check()` here are my results:

```r
==> devtools::check()

══ Documenting ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
ℹ Updating healthyverse documentation
ℹ Loading healthyverse
── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────── healthyverse 1.0.2.9000 ──
✔ healthyR      0.2.0          ✔ healthyR.ai   0.0.12    
✔ healthyR.data 1.0.2.9000     ✔ TidyDensity   1.2.4     
✔ healthyR.ts   0.2.7          ✔ tidyAML       0.0.1     
Warning: package 'TidyDensity' was built under R version 4.2.2
Warning: package 'tidyAML' was built under R version 4.2.2
── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── healthyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ healthyR.ai::kmeans_obj() masks healthyR::kmeans_obj()
✖ healthyR.ai::umap_list()  masks healthyR::umap_list()
✖ healthyR.ai::umap_plt()   masks healthyR::umap_plt()

══ Building ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX14FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX17FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
• CXX20FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\steve\Documents\GitHub\healthyverse/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'healthyverse':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
─  installing the package to build vignettes
✔  creating vignettes (9.3s)
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building 'healthyverse_1.0.2.9000.tar.gz'
   
══ Checking ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_               : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                      : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                     : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_PACKAGES_USED_IGNORE_UNUSED_IMPORTS_: FALSE
• NOT_CRAN                                     : true
── R CMD check ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  using log directory 'C:/Users/steve/Documents/GitHub/healthyverse.Rcheck'
─  using R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
─  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
─  using session charset: UTF-8
─  using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
✔  checking for file 'healthyverse/DESCRIPTION'
─  this is package 'healthyverse' version '1.0.2.9000'
─  package encoding: UTF-8
✔  checking package namespace information
✔  checking package dependencies (2.5s)
✔  checking if this is a source package ...
✔  checking if there is a namespace
✔  checking for executable files (352ms)
✔  checking for hidden files and directories ...
✔  checking for portable file names
✔  checking serialization versions
E  checking whether package 'healthyverse' can be installed (2.6s)
   Installation failed.
   See 'C:/Users/steve/Documents/GitHub/healthyverse.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
   
   See
     'C:/Users/steve/Documents/GitHub/healthyverse.Rcheck/00check.log'
   for details.
   
   
── R CMD check results ────────────────────────────────────────────────── healthyverse 1.0.2.9000 ────
Duration: 7.3s

❯ checking whether package 'healthyverse' can be installed ... ERROR
  See below...

── Install failure ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

* installing *source* package 'healthyverse' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'healthyverse':
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'healthyverse', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion(x)
  error: there is no package called 'tidyAML'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/steve/Documents/GitHub/healthyverse.Rcheck/healthyverse'

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

So we can see that tidyAML is infact attached.

Comment: Not sure about the version part (yet), but `Maintainer:` (if in `DESCRIPTION`) must be *"a single name followed by a valid (RFC 2822) email address in angle brackets"* (from [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file)). Do you have quotes in your real file? Try removing them and rerunning the test. (To just: `Maintainer: Steven Sanderson <blahblah@somemailhost.com>`)

Comment: thats just what I put here, the issue is strictly utils::packageVersion(x)[[1]] that fails during check for some reason but passes when entered into the command line

Comment: I wonder if it is because the package just made it today and there are no windows binaries yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `utils::packageVersion(x)`. The relevant bit is `error: there is no package called 'tidyAML'`.

Either the tidyAML package isn't installed on your computer, or it's not installed in a library on the path that R CMD check is using.

---

EDIT

After installing 350 (!!!) packages, I was able to replicate this error. Your `.onAttach()` calls `healthyverse_attach()`, which calls `core_unloaded()`, which checks whether any elements in `("healthyR","healthyR.data","healthyR.ts","healthyR.ai","TidyDensity","tidyAML")` are not attached to the search path (`core_unloaded()` is a misnomer because it's checking whether packages are *attached*, not whether they're *loaded*). Then, for any packages that aren't attached, you call `package_version()`, which calls `utils::packageVersion()` and fails for `tidyAML`.

This is an extremely convoluted pattern and I strongly suggest you stop using it. Especially because it's the source of your problem and you weren't able to track it down. The canonical pattern is documented in Writing R Extensions and is basically: packages listed in Depends will be attached when your package is attached, and packages listed in Imports will be loaded (but not attached) when your package is loaded. If you had done that, `R CMD check` would have let you know that you needed to add `tidyAML` to one of those.

Your specific problem is that you list `tidyAML` in `core` but you don't reference it in Depends or Imports, so your package namespace doesn't know it should use `tidyAML`, so `R CMD check` doesn't include it in the library of packages it uses during its checks. Also because of this, `tidyAML` wasn't one of the 350 packages I had to install, so it wasn't even on my system.

Comment: I don't see how it could not be found though, the reason being is that because I can call utils::packageVersion("tidyAML") in the same exact session on the console and get the correct answer. The package also definitely exists because I can call library(tidyAML) and it attaches to the session...so confused. Also the attach command in the meta package will attach tidyAML

Comment: Just trust @joshua-ulrich on this.  _When tests run_ they happen in a distinct, temporary, limited `.libPaths()` with only the packages you list.  So when you have an error it means the package was not present.

Comment: Which is *precisely* what [your DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/spsanderson/healthyverse/blob/main/DESCRIPTION) confirms.

Comment: Thank yoiu @JoshuaUlrich i didn't even think of looking at the DESCRIPTION file...